# How to display Game Center leaderboard from SKScene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, game-center

I am going to preface this by noting that their are a ton of other threads in here about this, however I can not get any of the methods listed to work.  Furthermore few of them are for the latest IOS and swift.

Anyway what I am trying to do is basically trigger a function inside of my view controller from a SKScene in order to show the Game Center leaderboard.  My function that I have inside of the UIViewController

```
func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(gameCenterViewController: GKGameCenterViewController!)
{
    gameCenterViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
func showLeader() {
    var vc = self.view?.window?.rootViewController
    var gc = GKGameCenterViewController()
    gc.gameCenterDelegate = self
    vc?.presentViewController(gc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I have tried acouple of methods to access and trigger this function but have been having the hardest time let alone accessing the function from the SKScene.  For some reason looking for the function by self.view doesn't work.  So how can I do this?

Comment: replace vc with your viewcontroller in which you are calling this method

Comment: How do I get to the view controller?

Comment: send it as a parameter right before presenting your SKScene and you'll have him in your SKScene

Comment: But like how do I get to it? Self.view doesn't work

Comment: Your viewcontroller is **self** in this case. Self.view is a view inside current viewcontroller

Comment: OH! I had no clue their was another layer.  So basically view controllers switch between View that have game scenes in them?

Comment: viewcontroller has a view, and the view has a SKScene